# Get html data from a web page which is populated by ajax

Tags: java, ajax

I've a web page on which certain section is being populated by ajax. I want this data. I've written a java program which posts the data and submit the form but unable to fetch the ajax content of the response.

My application is a core java app.

I'm simply posting data/submitting form with all request parameters set correctly. But not getting the data in response which is populated by ajax. :-(

How can i get that data? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Am I the only one who does not understand the question? Could you please paste your code?

Comment: I don't understand. Even if you manipulate the DOM using ajax, the values should be part of the POST as long as they are part of a form input field.

Comment: An ajax request does not differ from a normal request. So, as long as all request parameters are set correctly, you should get the desired response.
Of course, there may be all sorts of cookie/session/login-problems involved, but your problem does not seem to be Java related at all.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a software like FireBug to better understand what's going on in terms of requests and post variables.

Comment: I'm simply posting data/submitting form with all request parameters set correctly. But not getting the data in response which is populated by ajax. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard ajax requests have an additional HTTP `X-Requested-With` header. If they are filtering requests by type you will get nothing.

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*
...
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

As people commented try it on *Firefox* with *Firebug* addon and check the request headers.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are trying to use AJAX to get data from different domain, you are going to fail miserably. You would need to create a proxy for that.